# What do you call a piece of ribbon facing you the lining side?

Tags: word-request

I am having a hard time giving a name to the element representing a folded piece of a ribbon like can be seen on the picture:

[image]

There is a word for it in my native language, but unfortunately there is no entry for it in the dictionary, so chances are there is no direct translation.

**UPDATE**:

Sorry for puzzling you. The "ribbon" is what you see of the light-blue color where the word "Product" can be seen. The element in question is the orange triangle that represents a piece of that ribbon facing us with the back side. I understand it could be hard to comprehend.

Comment: I can't quite tell what you're referring to. Do you want a word for the object which says "Product" on its front (blue) side and has a blip of its orange reverse side showing? Or do you want a word for just the orange blip (if so, could you maybe provide a second picture, because it's kinda hard to tell what the orange blip is trying to represent)? Or do you just want a word for the reverse side of a ribbon?

Comment: The "ribbon" is  what you see of the light-blue color where the word "Product" can be seen.

The element in question is the orange triangle that represents a piece of that ribbon facing us with the back side. I understand it could be hard to comprehend.

Comment: You might have better luck asking this as [Webmasters.SE](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com). If there's a technical name for it, those folks might be able to help. If you're just looking for a word that would be intuitive to native speakers, I think _ribbon_ seems as good as any.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If OP is interested in the fact that the "orange triangle" shows the *opposite* side of the strip to that bearing the word "Product", I'd call it the [**obverse**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/obverse).

Normally, the "obverse" of a coin, for example, is the one with the monarch's head, or the principal design. But in other contexts I usually think of it as meaning "the **other** side*. Here's an instance of [the obverse of the label](http://973third.blogspot.co.uk/2011_09_01_archive.html) where it clearly means *the **underside** of the label*.

---

When referring to the entire folded portion *as an object* (as opposed to simply identifying the now-visible reverse face of the strip of material), I'd call that folded portion a...

> [**cleat**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cleat) *- a strip fastened across something to give strength or **hold in position***

Comment: In light of the clarification, you might want to remove the bit about "cleat", since that is clearly the wrong word. +1 for "obverse", however.

Comment: @Martha: Thanks. I've rearranged & reworded to clarify that *obverse* is my word of choice for exactly what OP is referring to. But I've kept a bit about "cleat" because I think it's potentially relevant.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean a clothing-label, printed or sewn on a bit of ribbon and sewn into the neckline of a garment (or waistline, etc.), then either of the following will work and are sometimes used.
• *[label](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/label#Noun)*, “A small ticket or sign giving information about something to which it is attached or intended to be attached”
• *[tag](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tag#Noun)*, “A small label”

Answer (score 0):

I believe you’re referring to the trim.